# Type mismatch: cannot convert from ActiveMQQueue to Queue

Tags: activemq-classic, message-queue

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-remoting-jms) to have my main application run as a server listening to messages and a supporting app/client to send messages using ActiveMQ remote server.

I am getting an issue on the client side when defining the queue as follows:

```java
@Bean Queue queue() {
    return new ActiveMQQueue("remotingQueue");
}
```

The issue is as follows:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ActiveMQQueue to Queue
```

Solutions suggested by Eclipse are:

- Add cast to 'Queue'
- Change method return type to ActiveMQueue.

The first solution gets rid of the issue, but when I'm running the app, it fails with the following message:

```
class org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue cannot be cast to class javax.jms.Queue
```

I'm getting the same issue when I try to run the app without casting.

Using the second solution suggested by Eclipse (i.e. Change method return type to ActiveMQueue) fixes the issue, but I'm not sure if configuring the queue this way will accomplish the goal of syncing up with the queue configured on the server side. The server side defines the queue as follows without issues:

```java
@Bean Queue queue() {
    return new ActiveMQQueue("remotingQueue");
}
```

Why does this definition works in one app, but it doesn't work in the second app?

Comment: What exact dependency/library are you using for `ActiveMQQueue`?

Comment: The import I'm using is as follows: import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue;

Comment: I'm not talking about the _import_. I'm asking about the specific dependency from Maven or if you're not using Maven then the name of the jar and what version of ActiveMQ "Classic" it came from.

Comment: The one relevant dependency I'm using is as follows: 

`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>`

Comment: This sounds like a classpath problem. Either wrong version or dupe of the JMS spec jar, or possibly mismatched versions of ActiveMQ jars.

Comment: Are you using Spring 6 or Spring Boot 3? If so, you need to use the activemq-client-jakarta v5.18.2 library to support the new 'jakarta.jms.Queue' namespace as part of the Java eco-system wide migration from javax.* to jakarta.*

Comment: What version of `spring-boot-starter-activemq` are you using?

Comment: @JustinBertram, currently 3.1.3.

FYI, I did edit the code as follows: 

`@Bean ActiveMQQueue queue() {
  return new ActiveMQQueue("remotingQueue");
 }`

The application compiles and runs, but I am trying to understand why it required that change in the first place when the other app didn't complain about `Queue`..

Comment: BTW, you should add these details to _your question_ rather than in the comments. Folks shouldn't need to read through the comments to understand the question.

Comment: @JustinBertram, this particular issue was sorted, but we are no longer using this implementation. So although the issue is solved, I never got the complete functionality to work - it used a deprecated method and we decided to go with a different implementation. Thanks for all the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using version 3.1.3 of `spring-boot-starter-activemq` then you are using this dependency transitively:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-client-jakarta</artifactId>
      <version>5.18.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This is the *Jakarta* dependency which means all the JMS objects use the `jakarta` namespace rather than the `javax` namespace. Therefore, your code should be using, for example, `jakarta.jms.Queue` instead of `javax.jms.Queue`.

I can't say why your other app isn't having the same issue. My guess is that it's using a different dependency or the runtime environment is different.

Lastly, you should avoid using implementation objects (e.g. `ActiveMQQueue`) whenever possible as it ruins the portability of your code and nullifies one of the main benefits of using an API like JMS in the first place.